# get XML from iframe cross domain with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I need a little if help to solve this question.
I need to get and XML from another server. My server can't make a request because of firewall.
With javascript(jquery), What's the solution to make and ajax call cross-domain?
I can make the request on client side but, How to get and xml node?
Usign a proxy script does not work for me...

Any idea?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access content from another frame that is in a different domain. The only types of requests this works for are <script src=""></script> tags. So you could dynamically add a script tag that points to a cross domain service that generates json and possibly get what you want that way.